# Radiation dose delivered to a cavity of air

Tags: radiation, medical-physics

I have a cavity of air which is exposed to a radiation source that liberates a known amount of charge in the cavity ( in the form of ionization ). What theory should I use to model the situation so I can determine the dose delivered to the cavity?

( edited to clear up what ionization means )

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Radiation sources don't release "a known amount of charge in the form of ionization". What do you mean by "dose"?

Comment: By charge I mean the effect the radiation has on the air in the form of ionization. Dose should just be the amount in grays, joules/kg, which is delivered to the air.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want the parameter "W", that relates ionization to energy. For air, it's [about 34 eV per ion pair](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31424563/).